# image cycle jQuery

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, jquery-cycle

Am looking for a very pared down, simple image cycling plugin. I dont want a lightbox, greybox, slimbox or any other box, just a simple way to show some images using arrows to click through, like this...   http://www.theapproach.co.uk/artists/phillip-allen/  but using simple triangles for navigation buttons to the right, like this... http://www.vilmagold.com/newpages/artists/hannahsawtell.htm

I've had big problems trying to get cycle.js to work and have spent way too much time faffing with it.  Here is a (non)working example http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/Untitled-4.html I'm not sure what the problem is, but praps the source shows a glaring error or two?

Maybe I should point out I'm using Dreamweaver cs5.5 and am very new to web design/ coding. Maybe there is something I am supposed to enable in the prog, or should be doing server side, (I'm with Dataflame).

About to give up with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a definite glaring error on your page: you didn't include jquery itself:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It goes above where you reference cycle. You may have any number of other errors, but start with that one. I also recommend getting [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or using Chrome's built-in developer tools. The console function of either will show you explicit JS errors, and they both have all sorts of great debugging tools.

Comment: Yup. The first error in my console is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. Easy pickins :)

Comment: ok this is wierd. I thought I had added it, so added it again, see the html here [link] http://jsfiddle.net/cress/2pZFU/ but after uploading, it disappears, just leaving the script open/close tags!! wtf?

Comment: oops, extra " hang on... http://jsfiddle.net/cress/2pZFU/1/ ...the  the library is there now, but so is the prob. Not such easy pickin's now :)

Comment: It's there now -- it's just cached in your browser. Hit the control button while you click reload to force your browser to ignore its cache. Also note you left a weird extra quote after the script tag. Now, why it does do anything is a separate matter...

Comment: so its actually working for you? I.E coming up as a single image with prev next buttons, which, when clicked reveal the next/prev image? Coz for me its just a line of 3 images. Even after doing the Ctrl/click reload you suggested. Could it be my pc settings?

Comment: You know that little animated emoticon, the black on white line drawing (and a lot of red) of a figure bashing in its skull against the keyboard until there's nothing left? Yeah, that.

Comment: I fixed it up a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/2pZFU/3/. A couple things: You had classes and IDs mixed up, and you didn't provide back/forward buttons.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6514/discussion-between-cress-and-isaac-cambron)

Comment: ah thankyou so much. I guess I got a bit tired. Thanks for your help. Am just gonna try changing the prev next to arrows, then upload & try it out