# Cycle.js images displaying in a row not as a slideshow

Tags: jquery, image-gallery, jquery-cycle

Can anyone tell me where the heck I'm going wrong with the implementation of this jQuery Cycle.js plugin please?

What do you see when you visit the link below? Coz all I see are 3 pics in a row, NOT a clickable prev/next slideshow.

http://www.cressidahaughton.co.uk/Untitled-4.html

Thanks in advance

Also related to Q [image cycle jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8773681/1114583)

Comment: question is rendered useless because the example is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is wrong, it should be **$('.pics')**, not **$('pics')**

---

Just for educational purposes:

When a selector starts without an special character (like hash, dot or colon) you basically are looking for tags. So in this case you are looking for:

```
<pics></pics>
```

instead of

```
<div class="pics"></div>
```

Comment: aaah, I'll give it a go... ...YAY! U absolute star! Thankyou!!

Comment: Oh rats, its transitioning by itself. I wanted the user to change the images by the buttons. U sorted one prob, fancy a go at the next?

Comment: thanks for the tip! Am teaching myself, so every bit of info is help!

Comment: use  autostop: 0 in the options... i think